# when to announce effect?

Tags: dnd-4e, charge

Can someone please settle an argument? When using an effect which modifies an attack roll such as reckless charge or elven accuracy, should the player announce it before/during the attack or after the DM tells them they've missed with the regular roll? Ex. Player charges enemy and DM informs them it's a miss. Can they then use the reckless charge feat to improve their attack roll as my friend says or am I right when I say they had to announce that they were using reckless charge at the begining of the charge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on the specific effect. Some have on their description the specific point where you can call for their bonus and rerolls (eg, any Augmentable power you must spend the Power Points before making any rolls). But there are some places where it may be a DM's call.

For example, the **Elven Accuracy** power have the following trigger line:

> Trigger: You make an attack roll and dislike the result

Is "the result" when you see the number on the dice, or when the DM tell you that you missed? The rules don't say. So, any option you choose can be said to be supported by the rules.

IMO, it is a good standard to allow the player to know if the attack missed before requiring him to make the reroll, since otherwise it would lead him to just try to metagame around the stats ("Bob missed on a 18, so my 17 clearly missed"), and this can lead to him actually asking you to NOT tell if the attack missed before he can finish all his mental calculations. And this lead to a slower pace, depending on how good your player is with math.

---

Reckless Charge, however, **do** have their timing listed. At the very start of the Benefit line it says:

> When you make a charge attack (...)

So, let's list the actual steps of a charge attack:

- You declare that you are going to make a charge
- You make your movement (at least 2 squares is required to charge)
- You make your attack roll
- You compare your attack roll with the target's defenses
- If you hit, you deal damage

You can make an argument that you "make a charge attack" either after declaring (so that your intention is clear), or before you make the attack roll (since after that the charge "attack" is already done). So, basically, the only doubt there is if you should declare that before or after you move. And since it is relevant for the feat (you could "avoid" an AC penalty for any provoked attack of opportunity if you can declare it later), in my personal opinion the RAI of this feat then requires you to declare its use at the same time you declare you are charging.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought because how could the charge have been reckless if you only decided to make it reckless at the end. Also with elven accuracy, i read it as meaning you don't like the number on the dice so you reroll.

Comment: @DynasXV I don't think it's ever occurred to me or anyone else in my group that "the result" could be anything *other* than hitting or missing. A number on a die is not a result, it's a part of the calculation that leads to a result.